# Tkinter Label and Entry

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I plan a mathematical game. I want the randint from label 1 + randint from label 2 to be calculated and then check if my entry is the same as the calculated number.

I want to add z1 to z2 and check if the Entry is the same but I don't know how I can add one random number to the other.

I can't add z1 to z2 so what is the way to do that?  Should this happen in the `if...else`?

from tkinter import *
    from random import *

```
fenster = Tk()
fenster.title("Mathe-Spiel")
fenster.geometry("300x300")

def anfang():
    z1 =label = Label(fenster, text=(randint(1,100)))
    label.pack()

    zp=label2 = Label(fenster, text="+")
    label2.pack()

    z2= label1 = Label(fenster, text=(randint(1,100)))
    label1.pack()

    a =label3 = Label(fenster,)
    label3.pack()


    e1=eingabe = Entry(fenster)
    eingabe.pack()

    e2=z1+z2

    def ausgabe():
        if (e1==e2):
            a.configure(text=(eingabe.get()))
        else:
            a.configure(text="Falsch")

    ergebnis = Button(fenster, text="ergebnis", command= ausgabe)
    ergebnis.pack()







anfangsknopf = Button(fenster, text="Fange mit dem Spielen an", command=anfang)
anfangsknopf.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: It's unclear what your actual question is. Maybe some background on what an Entry is, and what criteria would be used to determine equality.

Comment: Hmm, so i plan a mathematic game. I want that randint from label 1 + randint from label 2 get calculated and i want that it got checked if my entry is same with the calculated number. Clear ? If not i try to explain it on an other way. Thanks

Comment: These details should be in the text of the question. [Edit] the question and tell us what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error: You are trying adding 2 labels together (e2=z1+z2) but you expect that you add the values in your z1 and z2 text option!

You can get the right values while get text from z1 and z2 but I would do it in a different way.

like so:

```
from tkinter import Tk, IntVar, Button, Label, Entry
from random import randint

class Gui:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.summand1 = IntVar()
        self.summand2 = IntVar()
        anfangsknopf = Button(self.master, text="Fange mit dem Spielen an", command=self.create_widgets)
        anfangsknopf.pack()

    def create_widgets(self):
        """ create widgets on the fly """
        try:
            self.label1.destroy()
            self.label2.destroy()
            self.label3.destroy()
            self.eingabe.destroy()
            self.ergebnis.destroy()
            self.answer.destroy()
        except:
            print("No widgets destroyed")           
        self.fill_summands()
        self.label1 = Label(self.master, textvariable=self.summand1)
        self.label2 = Label(self.master, text="+")
        self.label3 = Label(self.master, textvariable=self.summand2)
        self.eingabe = Entry(self.master)
        self.ergebnis = Button(self.master, text="ergebnis", command= self.ausgabe)
        self.answer = Label(self.master, text="...")  
        self.label1.pack()
        self.label2.pack()
        self.label3.pack()
        self.eingabe.pack()
        self.ergebnis.pack()
        self.answer.pack()
        self.eingabe.focus_set()

    def get_random_nr(self):
        """ get random number """
        return randint(1,100)

    def fill_summands(self):
        """ set IntVar variables """
        r_number1 = self.get_random_nr()
        r_number2 = self.get_random_nr()
        self.summand1.set(r_number1)
        self.summand2.set(r_number2)

    def ausgabe(self):
        """ calculate addition """
        try:
            if self.summand1.get()+self.summand2.get() == int(self.eingabe.get()):
                print("Correct")
                self.answer.configure(text="Correct", fg="Green")
            else:
                print("Wrong")
                self.answer.configure(text="Wrong", fg="Red")
        except ValueError:
            print("Please set a number in Entry widget")
            self.answer.configure(text="Bitte gültige Nummer eingeben", fg="Red")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fenster = Tk()
    fenster.title("Mathe-Spiel")
    fenster.geometry("300x300")
    app = Gui(fenster)
    fenster.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks dude i appreciate that! <3

Comment: Please mark it as answered if that answer your question.